# Merge the two echo lines into one line using cut command

Tags: unix, echo, line, cut

Now I am printing two lines separately, I need to print it in single line.

```
echo $line cut -d "/" -f5 
echo $line | cut -d "/" -f9
```

I need both f5 and f9 values in single line.

```
f5 --> domain_name
f9 --> service_name
```

Expected output:

```
domain_name service_name
domain_name service_name
domain_name service_name
domain_name service_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this through `awk` command as well :

```
echo $line | awk -F"/" '{ print $5,$9 }'
```

`-F`: This is used to select the delimiter which in this case is `/`. And then we are printing the 5th and 9th column.

Comment: @balajibalehead You're welcome. If you want, you can accept it as a valid answer so that it helps other users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`man cut` educates us:

```
-f, --fields=LIST
       select  only  these  fields;   also print any line that contains 
       no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
```

so, using comma in:

```
$ cut -d / -f 5,9 file
```

is the right answer. However, the output delimiter will be `/` as well:

```
domain_name/service_name
```

unless you define it separately. `man cut`, here we come:

```
--output-delimiter=STRING
       use STRING as the output delimiter the default is to use the input delimiter
```

So:

```
$ cut -d / -f 5,9 --output-delimiter=\  file  # or --output-delimiter=" "
```

should output:

```
domain_name service_name
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you had the data in a variable and I used a file for testing. Well, it's `echo $line | cut -d / -f 5,9 --output-delimiter=" "` .

Comment: Than you for your input its working but including "/" between 5 and 9.

Comment: Well, it sure shouldn't due to `--output-delimiter=" "`- Can you check `man cut` on your system if it mentions that switch.